# Getting Specific Data from XML with Generic Tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Most tutorials I have found on doing this are based on xml that actually has useful tags. I'm trying to get a whole set of records based on one entry in the set, with XML that has very generic tags.

```
//saved as thisxml.xml in current directory
//note the empty entry in the second row
/*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Note>
    <ROW>
        <ENT>up</ENT>
        <ENT>Medium</ENT>
        <ENT>Red</ENT>
        <ENT>down</ENT>
        <ENT>Medium</ENT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <ENT>right</ENT>
        <ENT>High</ENT>
        <ENT>Purple</ENT>
        <ENT/>
        <ENT>High</ENT>
    </ROW>
</Note>
*/
```

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ParseGenericXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load("thisxml.xml");
            var selectRow = from r in document.Where(r=>(string)r.Element("ENT").Value=="Purple")
            select new
            {
                value1 = r.Element("ENT").Value,
                value2 = r.Element("ENT").Value,
                value3 = r.Element("ENT").Value,
                value4 = r.Element("ENT").Value,
                value5 = r.Element("ENT").Value
            };

            //selectRow results should be {"right","High","Purple",null,"High"}                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a real code? Your XML has 2 root nodes (i.e., it's malformed, and won't load). And XDocument is not enumerable as far as I remember.

Comment: @SergeyKrusch What are you trying to load it with?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not trying to load anything. I guess I'm asking here if you have tried to run the code that you've posted here against the data that you've posted here

Comment: I've edited the XML.  Does it work for you now? @SergeyKrusch

Comment: Why would calling `r.Element("ENT").Value` five times give you different values?

Comment: @Enigmativity It doesn't.  How would you go about doing this properly?

Comment: @user3250152 - Done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectRow =
    from r in document.Root.Elements("ROW")
    where r.Elements("ENT").Any(e => e.Value == "Purple")
    select r.Elements("ENT").Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
```